# install windows 10 in esxi 6 but disk speed in machine

Tags: vmware-esxi, ssd, windows-10, hpe

I have 2 Windows 10 in esxi 6 on ssd datastor but hard speed in task manager is 3 mb/s 
I install esxi in dl380 g9 server .
Is it normall speed ? 
How i can solve this problem?

Comment: So little detail here... a) is the SSD local to the DL380, if so what's the EXACT part number of HPE SSD/s, what's the model of disk controller it/they are connected to and if they're in an array what RAID level, b) is your ESXi host up to date with patches, c) Did you use the HPE-specific installation ISO to build this host or the 'vanilla' one from VMware, d) Are vmtools installed on the W10 VMs and what's the exact disk configuration for those VMs, also what machine model are you using for these VMs.

Comment: Thank you A) yes that are locally ,ssd evo samsung is used .controler is p440ar and 5 ssd use in raid 5. B) esxi 6 update 2 installed without any patch. C) esxi 6 custom hpe is installed. D) vmware tools is installed. This host install for test .

Comment: can you give the ssd model please, not all drive work good with HP server

Comment: amsung
4.8 out of 5 stars  15,171 Reviews
Samsung 850 EVO 500GB 2.5-Inch SATA III Internal SSD (MZ-75E500B/AM)

Answer (score 1):

You're facing this, very common, issue: https://www.reddit.com/r/vmware/comments/3r4zp8/esxi_6_unsuably_slow_disk_performance/

In few words, esxi is not for cheap raid controllers hardware. You need an hard raid with bbu and cache with write back mode to get rid of these. Or switch back to a non raid configuration with this hardware, and you'll have your IO performances back.

For the future please try to use better and deeper descriptions to ask your questions.

Comment: Tanks. Hpe costume vmware is for hpe and must support smart controller. This problem is also in sas 10 k . what's the plan for solve this problem

Comment: Perhaps try using supported SSDs, HPE don't support anybody else's disks, let alone consumer ones.

Comment: I try install a Windows server 2012 without esxi and copy speed is 1gb/s .so ssd and smart conroler and server are match . and my question is why it happened

Comment: @farshad indeed, the issue I linked in my answer it's a matter only through the VMware virtualization layer. Once again: you should read my link to understand what's going on.